# Update information on page in real time (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django

On my page I have a little envelope dropdown menu that displays the last 5 messages a user has received. I have a periodic function that runs itself to check for any new mail that may have come in. If a user has received a new message, how can I update that dropdown menu to remove the oldest message and show the newest?

Here's the HTML I have for the dropdown. I know the work needs to be done in the JavaScript somehow.

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
              {% for item in m reversed %}
                {% if forloop.counter0 < 5 %}
                <li class="message" id="{{item.id}}"> {{ item.body|truncatechars:30 }} </li>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
                <li><a href="/eventsearch/eventsearch/mailbox"> See All</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other client-side Javascript library? That would help immensely.

Comment: Using latest version of jQuery, sorry!

Comment: [Django notifications](https://github.com/pinax/django-notification) ?